# Create an own university logo with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, logos

I'd like to create my own university logo with tikz, because on the title page, it has a better resolution.

The logo must be look like that:

[image]

Can I write the text in the tikzpicture, too?

How can I use the right colors in this picture?

I need your help because i have not much experience with tikz.

---

My first example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill,blue] (0,0)--(2,1)--(2,0.1)--(0.9,-0.5)--(0,0);
    \draw[fill,gray] (-0.2,-0.1)--(0.9,-0.7)--(0.9,-1.3)--(-0.2,-0.7)--(-0.2,-0.1);
    \draw[fill,blue] (3.1,0.7)--(4.1,0.3)--(3.1,-0.1)--(3.1,0.7);
    \draw[fill,gray] (4.3,0.2)--(4.3,-0.7)--(2,-1.5)--(2,-0.7)--(4.3,0.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Imho you should better ask your university for a scalable version of the log instead of faking it.

Comment: What about using a tracer and exporting it then to TikZ? Next issue: most unis have some kind of a "press package" where you'd find the logos and whatnot, typically as PDF.

Comment: I would convert the [official logo](https://www.hs-osnabrueck.de/typo3conf/ext/hsos_core/Resources/Public/Images/logo.svg) to pdf and use that. No need to worry about colors, typefaces, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a color picker and you will get (approximately)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{1,158,227}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{197,197,197}
    \draw[fill,myblue] (0,0)--(2,1)--(2,0.1)--(0.9,-0.5)--(0,0);
    \draw[fill,mygray] (-0.2,-0.1)--(0.9,-0.7)--(0.9,-1.3)--(-0.2,-0.7)--(-0.2,-0.1);
    \draw[fill,myblue] (3.1,0.7)--(4.1,0.3)--(3.1,-0.1)--(3.1,0.7);
    \draw[fill,mygray] (4.3,0.2)--(4.3,-0.7)--(2,-1.5)--(2,-0.7)--(4.3,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the text, you should add it in your title page but outside the Ti*k*Z picture. But if you want,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{1,158,227}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{197,197,197}
    \fill[myblue] (0,0)--(2,1)--(2,0.1)--(0.9,-0.5)--(0,0);
    \fill[mygray] (-0.2,-0.1)--(0.9,-0.7)--(0.9,-1.3)--(-0.2,-0.7)--(-0.2,-0.1);
    \fill[myblue] (3.1,0.7)--(4.1,0.3)--(3.1,-0.1)--(3.1,0.7);
    \fill[mygray] (4.3,0.2)--(4.3,-0.7)--(2,-1.5)--(2,-0.7)--(4.3,0.2);
    \node[font=\huge\sffamily\bfseries] (upper) at (2,-3) {THIS IS SOME TEXT};
    \node[below=5pt of upper,font=\Large\sffamily] {HELLO WORLD};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Even better color

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{1,158,227}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{197,197,197}
\definecolor{textgray}{RGB}{85,85,85}
    \fill[myblue] (0,0)--(2,1)--(2,0.1)--(0.9,-0.5)--(0,0);
    \fill[mygray] (-0.2,-0.1)--(0.9,-0.7)--(0.9,-1.3)--(-0.2,-0.7)--(-0.2,-0.1);
    \fill[myblue] (3.1,0.7)--(4.1,0.3)--(3.1,-0.1)--(3.1,0.7);
    \fill[mygray] (4.3,0.2)--(4.3,-0.7)--(2,-1.5)--(2,-0.7)--(4.3,0.2);
    \node[font=\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{textgray}] (upper) at (2,-3) {THIS IS SOME TEXT};
    \node[below=5pt of upper,font=\Large\sffamily\color{textgray}] {HELLO WORLD};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And, to complete this, run XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Roboto}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{1,158,227}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{197,197,197}
\definecolor{textgray}{RGB}{85,85,85}
    \fill[myblue] (0,0)--(2,1)--(2,0.1)--(0.9,-0.5)--(0,0);
    \fill[mygray] (-0.2,-0.1)--(0.9,-0.7)--(0.9,-1.3)--(-0.2,-0.7)--(-0.2,-0.1);
    \fill[myblue] (3.1,0.7)--(4.1,0.3)--(3.1,-0.1)--(3.1,0.7);
    \fill[mygray] (4.3,0.2)--(4.3,-0.7)--(2,-1.5)--(2,-0.7)--(4.3,0.2);
    \node[font=\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{textgray}] (upper) at (2,-3) {THIS IS SOME TEXT};
    \node[below=5pt of upper,font=\Large\sffamily\color{textgray}] {HELLO WORLD};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I have a proposal, which is (maybe?) more coordinate-accurate than yours.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{1,158,227}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{197,197,197}
\definecolor{textgray}{RGB}{85,85,85}
    \fill[myblue] (-2.5,0) -- (-2.5,1) -- (0,2) -- (2.5,1) -- (2.5,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
    \fill[mygray] (0,0) -- (2.5,1) -- (2.5,0) -- (0,-1) -- (-2.5,0) -- (-2.5,1) -- cycle;
    \draw[line width=2mm,white] (0,0) -- (2.5,1) -- (0,2) -- (-2.5,1) -- cycle;
    \fill[white] (0,.5) rectangle (-1.25,-1) (0,2) rectangle (1.25,.5);
    \node[font=\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{textgray}] (upper) at (0,-3) {THIS IS SOME TEXT};
    \node[below=5pt of upper,font=\Large\sffamily\color{textgray}] {HELLO WORLD};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the view of a person who is not a student at your university, I can't be sure if the logo is precisely drawn.

Comment: Thanks for the colors...Is it the right way to create this logo with single coordinations? In my opinion it is an unattractive solution.

Comment: @nico.wagner The most beautiful thing is simpleness. Why do you want to make it uselessly complicated?

Comment: When I look other themes about tikz, there are always more complicated and never so easy created like my tikz creations. :(  But its okay, I do it with my way.

Comment: @nico.wagner If you want, I will complicate the code. But I must say that the output will be the same or worse. Ti*k*Z is not complicated and does not require projects to be complicated.

Comment: Yes, but only when it is a quick thing...

Comment: @nico.wagner I added a proposal. It is more accurate I think